Inject macro (vbaProject.bin) into a Docx file using OOXML SDK
I need your help for using OOXML SDK.
Here is the context : I'd like to inject some VBA macro using OOXML SDK.
My inputs :

a Word document following the OOXML specs (.docx)
a vbaProject.bin file containing the macros
a vbaData.xml containing some configuration

I try to implement it in 3 steps :

convert my docx to docm
inject the vbaData.xml
inject the vbaProject.bin

I have the error "DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackageException : 'The part cannot be added here.'" when I try to create a part of type VbaDataPart :
var vbaDataPart = workingCopyWordDocument.MainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<VbaDataPart>();
I've tried to create it in another part but I have the same issue : workingCopyWordDocument.AddNewPart<VbaDataPart>();
Here is my code :
public static WordprocessingDocument injectMacrosFromBinFiles(WordprocessingDocument sourceWordDocument, Stream vbaDataStream, Stream vbaProjectBinStream)
{
    // Create a working copy
    var openInEditableMode = true;
    var workingCopyWordDocument = (WordprocessingDocument) sourceWordDocument.Clone(new MemoryStream(), openInEditableMode);

    // Enable macros in document
    workingCopyWordDocument.ChangeDocumentType(WordprocessingDocumentType.MacroEnabledDocument);
    if (workingCopyWordDocument.MainDocumentPart == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("MainDocumentPart not found");
    }


    // Inject Macro
    var vbaDataPart = workingCopyWordDocument.MainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<VbaDataPart>();
    vbaDataPart.FeedData(vbaDataStream);

    var vbaProjectPart = workingCopyWordDocument.MainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<VbaProjectPart>();
    vbaProjectPart.FeedData(vbaProjectBinStream);

    return workingCopyWordDocument;
}

Do you have any idea on how to create this part ?

I've solved my issue by adding the VbaDataPart into the newly created VbaProjectPart.
The answer :
// Inject Macro
var vbaProjectPart = workingCopyWordDocument.MainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<VbaProjectPart>();
vbaProjectPart.FeedData(vbaProjectBinStream);

var vbaDataPart = vbaProjectPart.AddNewPart<VbaDataPart>();
vbaDataPart.FeedData(vbaDataStream);

Now my VBA macro is executed when the generated Docm is opened :)
